# Bootstrap 3 not centering items on mobile and tablets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need my layout to be at the center of mobile devices or tablets. Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row center-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-sm-1">
                    <img class="image" alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKNC5.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="col col-sm-11">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h3 class="col col-sm-12">Samsung Galaxy S5</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col col-sm-12">My Products Avaialble online and in stores</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col col-sm-12">Seller: My Product</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col col-sm-12">Quantity:
                                <input type="number" />
                            </span>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is mess up on mobile. I also added me a tag. Please help me to make items in center on mobile an tablets. JsBin http://jsbin.com/luxorapowe/1/

Comment: can you show your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RoySonasish, http://jsbin.com/luxorapowe/1/

Comment: You can't directly place .row in .row

Comment: Well @user123456 ... Try to replace `<div class="row center-block">` just to `<div class="row">`. After that, change the next `<div class="row">` to `<div class="box">` and create another `<div class="box-content">` inside it. And at least, include another `<div class="form-group">` for each line of `span` and `input` tags you have it...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before. You should place everything in a `.container` or `.container-fluid`. And don't nest a `.row` directly into another.

For centering the content on smaller devices just use a media query like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid
  {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

See this jsbin for example: http://jsbin.com/pukupejehu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing .container class that will center everything inside. And there is no need in center-block on a row class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added but no affect

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/svEQNHwXNxRsBs54cDk1?p=preview I think you should read up on the doc http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid